# Cannot find reference Imputer in__int__.py

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I am trying to write from "sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer", I am getting "Cannot find reference Imputer in__int__.py". I installed sklearn library and the pip version is 19.2.3. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue[enter image description here][1]

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imp = Imputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imp.fit(X[: , 0:3])
X = d.iloc[:, 0:3].values
print(imp.transform(X))
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback including the line with the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an import error it's probably because Imputer was moved from `sklearn.preprocessing` to `sklearn.impute` since Scikit-Learn 0.20.

use the following code instead

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
```

You should always use `SimpleImputer` instead of `Imputer`

check out the documentation of [SimpleImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html)